# Where does the wire (to pick the handcuffs) come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, die-hard-with-a-vengeance

Near the end of the movie [Die Hard: With a Vengeance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Hard_with_a_Vengeance) (at around 1:44), where [John](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McClane) and Zeus are handcuffed to the bomb in the ship, John talks about picking the lock. Suddenly he has a piece of a wire/cable in his mouth.

**What happened? Where did he get it from?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The wire came from the cable they used to get on the boat.  The cable was a braided wire cable and a splinter from it ended up in his shoulder as they reached the boat.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you see the splinter sticking in his shoulder? I watched this scene again and again and can't spot anything.

Comment: @unor Not so much see it explicitly.  Its just implied that when he was struck by it, a thread of the cable was still in his shoulder, then he picks it out of the wound with his teeth.